# Mounting React-Popup component throws render error

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

I'm trying to mount a react-popup component in the initial render of the page along with my actual app code (as recommended by the documentation) with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Popup />
        <App />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-outer">
                <div className= "main-middle">
                    <div className = "main-container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className = "large-12 columns">
                                <Canvas />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But I get this following error:

```
invariant.js:42 Uncaught Error: Popup.render(): A valid React element (or 
null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some 
other invalid object.
at invariant (invariant.js:42)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent 
(ReactCompositeComponent.js:828)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:234)
at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:701)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:520)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:368)
```

And the page fails to render entirely. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging the Popup component to console? You may be importing it incorrectly.

Comment: When I log, it seems to have imported correctly.
part of the output:
 ƒ Popup(props) {
     var _this;

     _classCallCheck(this, Popup);

     _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Popup.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Popup)).call(this, props));
     Object.def…

I installed the library with the standard "npm install react-popup"

Comment: Can you also provide `<Popup />` and `<App />` components code?

Comment: Popup is provided by the library. I can provide app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issue was that there are apparently two separate libraries reactjs-popup and react-popup, each recommended by two different helpful links. Here's [hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/introducing-reactjs-popup-modals-tooltips-and-menus-all-in-one-227de37766fa) and the official [docs](http://minutemailer.github.io/react-popup/). using reactjs-popup doesn't mount, but when I

```
import Popup from react-popup
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Move your ReactDom.render function below the App component so that it can access it. 
**Secondly**:
According to react DOM render method doc on official react website, it's signature looks like this: [react dom render](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html)

```
 ReactDOM.render(reactElement, domContainerNode);
```

or

```
ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])
```

even if you want to render multiple elements you can do something like this:

```
let eleArr = (
  <div>
    <Popup/>
    <App />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(eleArr, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I think it will be more cleaner approach.

working example [here](https://codepen.io/sheelpriy/pen/bKMKMo) i just created for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't solve the issue unfortunately .

Comment: @BijanMassoumi can you make a fiddle for this ? so that i can look into this further.

Comment: @BijanMassoumi ReactDOM.render function at the bottom. i have updated my answer, it must solve your issue.

Comment: I understand that is the common design pattern for rendering. The issue is that <Popup /> specifically isn't rendering, despite the fact i've downloaded and imported the package correctly as specified by the documentation.